# regex in Notepad++ find/replace where string contains special characters

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

Using **Notepad++** Regex find/replace.

I am trying to find and replace specific text in mysql file:

```
<h1 style=\"color: #fffff3;\">bla bla bla</h1></td>
```

What I am trying to do is to change 'bla bla bla' with some image.
So the expected output is:

```
<h1 style=\"color: #fffff3;\"><img height="72" src="http://www.example.com/image.png" width="72"></h1></td>
```

What I tried so far:

`<h1 style=\"color: #fffff3;\">(.*?)</h1>` from [this stack post](https://superuser.com/a/986505).

How to find and replace while take care of special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lookahead and lookbehind Regex: `(?<=<h1 style=\\\"color: #fffff3;\\\">)(.*?)(?=<\/h1>)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hhsU4u/1)

Comment: Thank you!, it worked like charm! Excellent , Appreciated